# How to convert dateTime to yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, time

I have seen plethora of posts asking how to convert yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ to dateTime, but I didn't see the other way around.

I am trying to create an array of object and give each object `created_at` attribute. Currently I am using `new Date()`. It gives me `Fri Jul 21 2017 12:37:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)`. I need to give it date-time in format `2017-07-21T00:00:56.273Z` instead.

```
  ...
  var timeNow = new Date();
  newWeekScoresHolder.push(
    {
      completed_at: "",
      point: 0,
      student_id: student.id,
      week: maxWeek,
      id: id + index,
      created_at: timeNow //Fri Jul 21 2017 12:37:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)
    }
  );
```

How can I change `timeNow` format to format similar to `2017-07-21T00:00:56.249Z`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toISOString()` to get ISO date format:

```
var timeNow = new Date().toISOString();
```

Comment: Nice answer, wide better than mine!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [moment](https://momentjs.com/), this way:

```
let date = moment().format('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ');
console.log(date);
```

Hope it helps